# assembly language project "English word rotational billboard"

Tags: emu8086

I am working on a project on assembly language and I need help with
what rotational billboard is? and I need you guys to give me a program that make English word rotational billboard on the screen of emu8086

in my understanding I try to display some text on the screen of emu8086 and rotate it from right to left
but I couldn't achieve anything